# how kill process with random name?

Tags: random, cmd, shellexecute, kill-process

i have a file in "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\" with name Protector-(random 4 letters).exe   . so you can see that the name of the file is random.

now i want to write a c++ code to kill this file's process.
plz tell me that code to kill this file.
i found ShellExecute() function to run a command (taskkill) and kill the process but i dont know how i can kill a process with **random** name by this function!
this is a code that i found for ShellExecute():

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe ", L"taskkill /f /fi ""IMAGENAME eq Protector-(random 4 letters).exe""", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: store file names in array, and randomly select one index and attempt to kill the process

Comment: i dont have file names!
the names are random!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`Taskkill /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Taskkill supports the Wildchar `*` character

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", L"taskkill /f /im \"Protector-*\"", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like 'ps aux | grep Protector' and that should isolate your process. But make sure you don't have anything else by the name Protector in it

Comment: i want a cmd command but 'ps aux | grep Protector' is an unix commands!

Comment: so i want some thing like ps aux | grep Protector for windows!
can any one help me?